Python with CustomTkinter - Splitting app across multiple python files
I currently have a small app using CustomTkinter. The whole app is an instance of Class App. The Class has some methods to draw the sections of UI, and methods that do background tasks that can update the UI, and it works great.
However, as my app grows, I think I need to split it across multiple files so it's easier to maintain. The UI build method can be in a file, any complex components of the UI can be Classes in their own files, any methods for processing file i/o can be in a file etc.
What I don't understand is how to split it up and manage the Class structure. In my UI.py file, should I have a UI class for the UI that inherits from (customtkinter.CTk)? Then in my main.py file, do self.ui = UI()? If I do that, how will methods from another slave file be able to update controls in the ui.py file?
I think understand the concept of classes fairly well, but I can't wrap my head around this. All of the OOP tutorials I find are based on basic fruit/dog/vehicle Class examples. But I'm using the CustomTkinter framework and inheriting things from that, so I don't know what best practice is.
If someone knows of a particular tutorial for splitting CustomTkinter across multiple py files, that would be great!
I tried to put just methods from a class in a separate file, which actually does function fine, but I got lots of 'Unresolved Attribute Reference' IDE warnings. I probably shouldn't proceed with these warnings I guess, and want to make it correct for the future.

you may have to send self.ui to other class as parameter.

I think it is not good idea to split all UI to one file and functions to another file. UI has to import functions from other files and use them in UI class. You use inherit CustomTkinter to add some functions to this class.

I made it work with the main ctk windows called App running in main.py and creating another file called "Frame.py" for this example, and created a frame class in the same directory which I imported to main.py and added to the App Class. This way works fine with app CTk classes as well as with functions.
Main.py:
import customtkinter
import Frame


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("400x400")

        self.frame1 = Frame.Frame1(self)
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)


app = App()
app.mainloop()

Frame.py:
import customtkinter

class Frame1(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Hello!")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)

